# Python Alphabetical order by sort method shows wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just learning python and I came across a code for sorting words alphabetically.

My code is:

```
my_str="Welcome to Python"
words = my_str.split()
words.sort()
print("The sorted words are:")
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

My result comes out as:

The sorted words are:

```
Python

Welcome

to
```

I mean it is sorted alphabetically then it should result as

```
Python

to

Welcome
```

I am totally confused and unable to proceed forward in learning process, your insights would be so helpful.

Comment: Capital letters come before small letters in ASCII

Comment: To sort case-insensitively, you can use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold). Something like `some_list.sort(key=str.casefold)`.

Answer (score 0):

capital letters are smaller that small letter

```
>>> 'A' < 'a'
True
```

If you want to sort without making a distinction between capital and small letters use this.

```
>>> words.sort(key=str.lower)
>>> words
['Python', 'to', 'Welcome']
```

If you are using python3 you can use 
`str.casefold` for comparison this will handle unicode comparison as well.

```
>>> words.sort(key=str.casefold)
>>> words
['Python', 'to', 'Welcome']
```

Comment: You can just use `str.lower` instead of a lambda, or [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), which is specifically for caseless comparison, and handles Unicode properly.

Comment: thank you so much, that helped to clear my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
my_str="Welcome to Python"
some_list = my_str.split()
some_list.sort(key=str.casefold)

print("The sorted words are:")
for word in some_list:
    print(word)
```

Output will be:

```
Python
to
Welcome
```